# Yissachar - Zevulin Torah business partnership

Tags: money, adult-learning

When you have a Yissachar Zevulin partnership does Zevulin have to give exactly half of what he earns to Yissachar? In addition suppose Yissachar misses a day does he have to reimburse Zevulin?

Answer (score 3):

No he doesn't  Not all partners get an equal share, and not all profits go into the pockets of the partners.  Here is an [entire sefer](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/35209) written on the subject.

Comment: Same author as Shu"t Yaskil Avdi?

Comment: No.  Actually it is his father, Shalom Hedayya, and Rosh Yeshiva before the Yaskil Avdi.

Comment: Mekubal, Yiyasher kohacha for a great source!

Answer (score 1):

[Rav Moshe Feinstein](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=922&st=&pgnum=281) understands the [Remah and the Shach](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9147&st=&pgnum=137&hilite=) to both be saying that they must split 50/50.

This is a very complex Halachik discussion that has been addressed by many people greater than us. One should read this article at [Hakira](http://www.hakirah.org/Vol%205%20Buchman.pdf) to at least expose himself to some of the issues involved in this discussion.